# Reading cookies from another domain lavel by means of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

In my current project I'm trying to read cookie (SMSESSION in the screenshot below) set on the root domain level (es.corpintra.net). But since my application is running in a sub-domain (encoma-plus-dev.es.corpintra.net) the cookie is not visible at all programatically. I can observe it in the browser's developer tools though, from where the screenshot is taken.

The code snippet I'm using is quite simple:

> $cookies.SMSESSION

If for testing purposes I add a dummy cookie 'foo' then it is accessible but as the screenshot shows, the cookie has different domain and path.

Can you tell me how I can access the cookie SMSESSION by means of AngularJS or JavaScript?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: "AngularJS or JavaScript" — Angular is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

JavaScript can only access cookies belonging to the HTML document the JavaScript is running in.

If you want to get them from another origin, then you'll need it (said origin) to expose the cookie data through some non-cookie method.